# react , using <br> inside .map inside for (object)

Tags: reactjs

I know in react you can't use `<html>` like strings,  i'm looking for a solution but i don't see clear, how in this complex logic  you can to insert a `<br/>` object and not like string, because variable 'newvalue' need to store and conditionally add br to separate elements in rows.

```
  let values = JSON.parse(value);
  let newvalue = '';
  values.map((item) => {
    for (const key in listViewField.subfields) {
      let nameField = key;
      if (typeof item[nameField] !=='undefined') {
        newvalue += item[nameField]+ ' ';
      }
    }
    // if (newvalue.trim() !=='') newvalue += '<br/>'; // doesn't work
  });
  value = newvalue;
  return <div key={keyIndex}>{value}</div>;
```

Comment: Do you _need_ to use `<br />` tags? Would rendering each item in `<div>` not work for your case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than using map, you can just iterate over your values and push them into an array.

```
let values = JSON.parse(value);
let contents = [];

for (let value of values) {
  contents.push(<span key={value.key}>{value.name}</span>);

  if (value.condition) {
    contents.push(<br key={`${value.key}-br`} />);
  }
});

return <div>{contents}</div>;
```

Don't forget to add a unique key to each item.

Comment: very amazing answer, I did not know that you can add jsx elements into array, react is wonderful ! angular 2,4,5 goodbye

Comment: Just remember that a JSX element is really just a call to `React.createElement()` and that function takes either an element or an array of elements as its final argument.

Comment: Works great! One improvement might be to use `reduce` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To add different option, if you want to use it with `map` and your `item` is simple string, then you can do something like this.

```
items.map((item, key) => {
    <span style={{whiteSpace: 'pre'}} key={key}>{item + '\n'}</span>
});
```

Note that I have added `style={{whiteSpace: 'pre'}}` and `+ \n`

Comment: It works if I remove the curly brackets